# firebaseの無料プラン（Sparkプラン）でプロジェクトを削除する方法を教えてください。

Tags: firebase

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

firebaseの[無料プラン（Sparkプラン）](https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=ja)でプロジェクトを削除する方法を教えてください。

#### 【質問の補足】

1.

[Firebaseのサポートページ](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000104?hl=ja)を確認すると「プロジェクトを完全に削除する」という見出しがあり、
「[全般] 設定ページ下部の  [プロジェクトを削除] をクリックします。」という記述がありますが、この記述に該当する部分がどこにあるのか分かりません。

2.

firebaseのプロジェクトを削除するために確認をしているページは以下の2つです。スクリーンショットにしています。
http://takaiba.net/stackoverflow/stackoverflow20190429_1.png
http://takaiba.net/stackoverflow/stackoverflow20190429_2.png

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
以下の手順で行うとプロジェクトの削除が可能です。

```
Firebaseのコンソール画面からプロジェクトの管理画面にログイン
↓
歯車のアイコン
↓
[プロジェクトの設定]
↓
（画面下部にある）[プロジェクトの削除]のリンクをクリックする
```

プロジェクトを削除するまでの操作画面については、個人で運営しているブログサイトに[記事](https://e-yota.com/webservice/firebase_project_delete_restore/)としてまとめています。また合わせて、一度削除したプロジェクトの復元方法についても言及しています。